# Combining Arrayformula with textjoin to eliminate delimiters

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use an arrayformula to join a string of cells in the same row as per picuture. This formula needs to automatically copy down to any new rows that are added.  The formula I have so far seems to be the only one that returns at least something. I have googled and tried all sorts of join, textjoin to eliminate delimiters when a cell is empty but I keep getting all sorts of errors.

Also, note in column L I only want part of the cell, the city name, not state and zip code, which is why I added the Left function.

I would also like a header in row D1 "Summary".

Also, another problem I am having with the Arrayformula, is that any new rows that are submitted by my script, get pasted way down the bottom of the sheet, skipping blank rows.  I think it sees the array formula as part of the last row even though those rows are blank.  The only workaround I have so far is to delete all empty rows after my table, so I have the little [add 1000 more rows at bottom] after my last data row.  But this then effects the filter range.  The filter range does not seem to update automatically when new rows added.  Maybe I need to address each of these issues as a new question in Stakoverflow?

[image]

[Jobs Database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15BipaJk2uGm7RgXFB6JVXdTBBFH0OdbR8cAO8C-F6lk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The most efficient way to receive help would be to share a link to your sheet (or to a copy of your sheet with at least A:L and a few rows of data, as shown in your post image. Just be sure, if you choose to share such a link, that you set the link's Share permission (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor," so that those here can actually access the sheet, test and leave any solutions they devise for you.

Comment: In looking at this again, I can certainly offer a solution and, I believe, an improvement on what you're trying to do. I'll check back tomorrow to see if you've shared a link to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you Erik.  I have edited the main post with a copy.  After taking it for a test run today with all our data, I find it extremely slow.  That little green bar at the top right of the screen seems to progress really slow when I add data.  It is quite a big project.

Comment: Marianne, I had no trouble opening or loading your linked copy of the spreadsheet (1 to 2 seconds). I will post my solutions below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete everything from 'Jobs Database'!D:D (you can always undo it if you aren't happy with the formulas proposed). Then place one of the following two formulas in D1, though I recommend the second of the two.

The following formula will produce results in keeping with what you showed in your post and what is currently in the sheet (though my formula creates a cleaner result, because it addresses more potential issues than your original formula):

`=ArrayFormula(FILTER(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Summary",B:B&IF(C:C="",," - "&REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(C:C),"^-",""))&" - "&IF(H:H="",,H:H&" x ")&G:G&IF(I:I="",," - "&I:I)&" - "&IF(J:J="",,REGEXREPLACE(J:J,",$","")&" - ")&IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(L:L,"(.+)[\s\w]{8}")&" - ")&"ID: "&A:A),A:A<>""))`

This formula is written to accommodate the fact that you've got column-level sorting in place. The `FILTER` clause surrounding everything inside also assures that the results only run as far down as you have data in Column A. This should eliminate the issue you were having with new rows being added after blanks.

I recommend the layout produced by this second formula, however:

`=ArrayFormula(FILTER(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Summary",B:B&IF(C:C="",,CHAR(10)&TO_TEXT(C:C))&CHAR(10)&IF(H:H="",,H:H&" x ")&G:G&IF(I:I="",,CHAR(10)&I:I)&CHAR(10)&IF(J:J="",,REGEXREPLACE(J:J,",$","")&CHAR(10))&IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(L:L,"(.+)[\s\w]{8}")&CHAR(10))&"ID: "&A:A),A:A<>""))`

In my opinion, the use of line breaks between information is cleaner and therefore easier to read.

Both formula options would require selecting all rows, right clicking, choosing "Resize rows" and selecting "Fit to data" for full viewing.

I have added two sheet ("Erik Help 1" and "Erik Help 2") with each of the above formulas in place, respectively).

Comment: Thank you so much Erik.  It works beautifully.

Comment: You're welcome. If you would, please take a moment and check the icon to mark this post as "Best Answer." This allows the contributor community to see from the main dashboard which issues are already fully resolved; and it allows future site visitors to quickly find the most relevant answers. Thanks.